# setting up matlab multicore computing

Tags: multithreading, matlab

I'm trying to use something like this in matlab

```
parfor i = 1 : 100
    disp( sprintf('process %d\n', i) ); 
end
```

how do I setup the number of cores I want to use (possibly inside the script)? At this moment I always see the same (sorted) sequence.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
matlabpool open X
```

where `X` is the number of cores you'd like to run your computation on.

Comment: Do you know how to set ClusterSize?

Comment: To set the ClusterSize property for a configuration, you need to open the configuration editor - Parallel menu, then "Manage Configurations".